# Complement of invariant subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Assuming that I have a given vector space $V$ and a subspace $U$, which is invariant under an endomorphism $A\in End(V)$. I want to prove that $U^\perp$ is also invariant on $A$ .

Comment: Unless your endomorphism preserves the bilinear form, this is false.

Comment: Do you mean $U^{\perp} = \{ y \in V \, | \, \forall x \in U, \quad y \cdot x = 0 \}$ or the other definition that doesn't involve inner products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean
$$
U^{\perp} = \{ y \in V \, | \, \forall x \in U, \quad y \cdot x = 0\},
$$
then letting $y \in U^{\perp}$, if $A$ is a symmetric endomorphism with respect to the inner product, it works like this : $Ay \in U^{\perp}$ because
$$
Ay \cdot x = y \cdot A^{\top} x = y \cdot Ax = 0
$$
because $Ax \in U$. Otherwise you can't do much in general.

If you mean
$$
U^{\perp} = \{ y \in V' \, | \, \forall x \in U, \quad y(x) = 0 \}
$$
where $V' = \{ \varphi : V \to \mathbb R \, | \, \varphi \text{ is linear and continuous } \}$ (i.e. the dual space of $V$), then $U^{\perp}$ is stable by the action of $A$ on $V'$ given by 
$$
(y \circ A)(x) \overset{def}= y(Ax).
$$
(Notice how $(y \circ A) \circ B = y \circ (AB)$ so that you have a *right* action of $\mathrm{End}(V)$ on $V'$, not a *left* action.) Then it follows that $U^{\perp}$ is invariant by $A$ because if $y \in U^{\perp}$, then $y(x) = 0$ for all $x \in U$, hence since $Ax \in U$, $(y \circ A)(x) = y(Ax) = 0$.

Hope that helps,